# JAVA & MYSQL unreachable code

Tags: java

Hey I have small problem but I can't fix it :( I use mysql + bukkit libraries, and when I want use one of the methods I get error of unreachable code

**Main.java**

```
package Hester.CrafMe;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.bukkit.ChatColor;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;
import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {

    protected static final Logger log=Logger.getLogger("Minecraft");
    private static final String ALPHA_NUM = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    public Colorizer colorize = new Colorizer();
    public MySQL sql = new MySQL();
    public static Main plugin;



public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String commandLabel, String[] args) {
            final FileConfiguration config = this.getConfig();
            Player player = (Player) sender;
            int LANG = config.getInt("PlayerConfig."+player.getName()+".language");

        //uKEY(unikalny kod)
        if (command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("ukey")){
            String Private_uKEY = uKEY(7);

            if(LANG == 1){
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Twoj unikalny kod to: "+ ChatColor.YELLOW + Private_uKEY);
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Podany kod wpisz na stronie "+ ChatColor.YELLOW + "www.crafme.net");        
                return true;
            } else {
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Your unique code is: "+ ChatColor.YELLOW + Private_uKEY);
                player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Enter the code on the page "+ ChatColor.YELLOW + "www.crafme.net");
                return true;
            }

            sql.uKEY(Private_uKEY, player.getName());
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

**MySQL.java** and here i connect to sql but i have problem with unreachable code

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Date;

import org.bukkit.event.Listener;

public class MySQL implements Listener {
    private Connection connect = null;
    private Statement statement = null;
    private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
    private ResultSet resultSet = null;

  public void connect() throws Exception {
      try {
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
          connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost....?"+ "user=test&password=whatever");
          statement = connect.createStatement();

          ... more code

      } catch (Exception e) {
          throw e;
      } finally {
          close();
      }
  }
```

what is wrong ?

Comment: Which code is unreachable? Is there anything more in your error?

Comment: I think you missed problematic code part.

Comment: `catch (Exception e) {
              throw e;
          }` is absolutely redundant. Remove this piece of code.

Comment: If the code that appears to be in Main.java actually appears as you have it there, it needs to be inside of a class. You don't have a class or a method to contain the instantation of your MySQL object and the calls to its methods.

Comment: sql.uKEY(Private_uKEY, player.getName()); there is unreachable code this is on class public class Main extends JavaPlugin { 
 public Colorizer colorize = new Colorizer();
 public MySQL sql = new MySQL();
 public static Main plugin;

public boolean onCommand( ) {
sql.uKEY(Private_uKEY, player.getName());
}

Comment: @user1366028 Please post the complete code as an edit in your question.

Comment: @user1366028 Thanks, that shed some light.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to point out where are you getting the *unreachable code* message. With the current information all we can do is guesswork.

Still, some examples of common dead code cases are

```
public String getProperty() {
    return "property";
    System.out.println("Dead code"); //Code after a return statement
}
```

or

```
//Method...
throw new Exception();
//Unreachable code from now on, after an exception is thrown.
```

In this case, you have an `if` and its `else` both returning a value, hence the code after those statements won't be executed.

```
if (command.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("ukey")){
    String Private_uKEY = uKEY(7);
    if(LANG == 1){
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Twoj unikalny kod to: "+ ChatColor.YELLOW + Private_uKEY);
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Podany kod wpisz na stronie "+ ChatColor.YELLOW + "www.crafme.net");        
        return true; //Returning a value
    } else {
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Your unique code is: "+ ChatColor.YELLOW + Private_uKEY);
        player.sendMessage(ChatColor.RED + "Enter the code on the page "+ ChatColor.YELLOW + "www.crafme.net");
        return true; //Returning a value on the else too
    }
    //Since both the if and the else return something, the code below won't be executed.
    sql.uKEY(Private_uKEY, player.getName()); 

}

return false;
```

You need to work on what do you want to do there.

Comment: yeah ! you have right, when I remove return true; all working perfect :D Thanks !